# visual studio 2017 upgraded cl is not a full path and was not found in the PATH

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Error details:

```
Make build 
CD: ./_build
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
      cl
    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):    
   The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
      cl
    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
See also “D:/MYNTAI-Work/d-tmp/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log”. 
See also “D:/MYNTAI-Work/d-tmp/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log”. 
make: *** [Makefile:53: build] Error 1
```

It was fine before I upgraded Visual Studio 2017. This error will be reported after the upgrade. I ran `vcvarall.bat` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect error logs to be in the question post itself, **as a text**, not as an *image*. Please, [edit] your question post and paste textual error log. You may format this log as a code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.